# Center button within a div

Tags: css, html, button, centering

I centered all divs groups with `div { width: 95%; margin: 0 auto; }` but 1 div that has button is not centering, I tried also to place `text-align: center;` to various places but it not worked.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A9UNA/3/)

EDIT: Forgot to mention I want to center for @media (max-width: 480px) only
Image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

It now works with 95%. [SEE NEW UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/A9UNA/10/)

Here's what I added to your media query:

```
.pure-controls{
margin:0 auto;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
}
.pure-controls button{
width:95%;
display:inline-block;

}
```

I think I figured it out. [SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/A9UNA/7/)

I added this to your media queries:

```
.pure-controls{
width:100%;
text-align:center;
}
.pure-controls button{
display:inline-block;

}
```

Comment: Its still not working, if you change width to 95% the button is not centered.

Comment: that's why it has to be 100% lol didn't you want it to be 100% like in your picture?

Comment: I don't want it to be 100, my other divs worked with 95% but the last div not working.. I want to have 2.5% space left and right.

Comment: Well yes its working now for media (max-width: 480px) but the button is now too big at media (min-width: 480px)

Comment: if you would've just added my snipped of code to your code it would've worked fine. I was messing with the code and I forgot to change it. But here is the updated updated super new version: http://jsfiddle.net/A9UNA/10/

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
 <div class="pure-controls" style="text-align:center">
```

container of the button should have `text-align:center`

Comment: forgot to mention I want to center only for @media (max-width: 480px)

Comment: @Loclip what do u mean by that?

Comment: If you resize window to smaller with smaller than 480px I apply different style. I want the button to be centered there.

Comment: Try moving container of your button inside @media

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42452/discussion-between-aditya-ponkshe-and-loclip)

Answer (score 0):

You missed for **`pure-controls`** class

```
.pure-controls {
  text-align: center
}
```

Also this div is slightly positioned away from the others.  Even after centering the button will be little away from center.

Comment: forgot to mention I want to center only for @media (max-width: 480px)

Answer (score 0):

make its Enclosing div's class pure-controls have this css

```
.pure-controls {
  text-align: center
}
```

[`Demo fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/A9UNA/4/)

Comment: forgot to mention I want to center only for @media (max-width: 480px)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this css:**

```
.pure-controls {
    margin: 1.5em 0 0 10em;
    margin-left:10%;
}
```

**or**

```
.pure-controls {
    margin: 1.5em 0 0 10em;
    text-align: center;
}
```